# The .SVC file inside Azure "Kudu" is empty

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have the following asp.net web application which contain a .SVC, as follow:-

[image]

the .SVC file inside visual studio contain this code:-

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ProjectUpdateSystem.RER" CodeBehind="RER.svc.cs" %>
```

I deploy the above VS project to Azure web app using this command:-

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group "PUS" --name "TGroupPUSRER" --src "C:\pus\bin.zip"
```

but when i try to edit the RER.SVS file inside Kudu as follow:-
[image]

it showed any empty file as follow:-
[image]

so can anyone advice? is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is there inside the file. But for some reason (may be a bug?) it cannot show the content.

Assuming you have a `sample.svc` file having some content, to see the content, you can use either of the following PowerShell or cmd commands:

- `Get-Content sample.svc`
- `type sample.svc`

Comment: thanks foer the reply . so my `.svc` is not having any problem, and the issue is that i can not edit it using kudu? but the `.svc` should be hosted and working fine?

Comment: @testtest I tested using a real svc file and everything works well. Just created a simple web form application, added a service having a hello function, then deployed on app service. Turned off https only, connected through a client and everything was working well.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same Issue , It seems its a bug in the Kudu. The problem is with the *.svc extension file.

Try creating a new file with ".svc" extension and it will immediately give you an 404 error.
[image]

You can use "App Service Editor" instead of kudu.

Found the existing defect in github 
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2872

Comment: ok i see , but is the .svc file working well?or it is facing issues since i can not edit/delete it?

Comment: Yes file works file. Its just that you can't use kudu to edit/delete it.